# Multiple user accounts

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-accounts

It seems a user called 'Rafal Burchard' is making multiple accounts, about 1 every 2 days.

- [User 1065](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/1065/rafal-burchard)
- [User 1069](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/1069/rafal-burchard)
- [User 1073](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/1073/rafal-burchard)
- [User 1075](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/1075/rafal-burchard)

Is this allowed? Should the accounts be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that those are the same users. I will send a request to the Community team to have those accounts merged.

**Update:** The Stack Exchange Community Team has completed the merge.

Comment: Thank you for the quick action. Is the user notified of this, so he knows that he shouldn't create multiple accounts anymore?

Comment: @THelper There are moderation tools that will allow us to contact him , but we can also contact him via chat as well to discuss the issue. The user has enough reputation to be enter the chat.